# text on bottom left corner of screen

Tags: css

I want to keep the name of my portal on the bottom left corner of the browser window in a vertical direction.

The following is the css styling i am using but the text is coming with a margin to the left and bit of text is also getting clipped.

```
.rotate {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
        font-size:60px;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
```

can someone help in correcting my css class please.

here's the [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshman553/k1yuxjo1/) link

thank you.

lakshman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one :

```css
.rotate {
    transform-origin:0% bottom;
    -moz-transform-origin:0% bottom;
    -webkit-transform-origin:0% bottom;
    -o-transform-origin:0% bottom;
    -ms-transform-origin:0% bottom;
    transform:rotate(-90deg) translateY(100%);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg) translateY(100%);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg) translateY(100%);
    -o-transform:rotate(-90deg) translateY(100%);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg) translateY(100%);
 display: block;
 writing-mode: tb-rl;
 position: fixed;
    left:0; bottom:0;
 margin: auto;
    font-size:60px;
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate">
    LeftBottom
</div>
```

<strike>If You change `font-size`, then change `height` and `line-height` too. You can add `padding` too, but then You don't need change `height` and `line-height` (only if `font-size` is changed).</strike>

There is **[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/1p9ff91r/1/)** with changed `font-size` (<strike>`height`, `line-height`</strike>) and `padding` (just to see how it's working).

**UPDATE :** I made changes by removing `height` and `line-height`. Here and in fiddle example. It's working better.

Answer (score 1):

look at this updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k1yuxjo1/4/), when you rotate the text it does so from the middle of the div, so when its -90 degrees and on the bottom of the screen part of the div will rotate beneath the window.

```
.newRotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    font-size:70px;
    position: fixed;
    left: -100px;
    bottom: 110px;
}
```

To alleviate this I changed the left and bottom position

Answer (score 0):

You can try this and see if its what you are looking for.

```
.rotate {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    font-size:60px;
    position: fixed;

    left: -80px;
    bottom: 90px;
}
```